# Trying to understand a Monty Hall simulation code in Python

Tags: python, probability

As part of a classroom exercise, I'm trying to understand the code of a Monty Hall simulation found here: https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4452741-decouvrez-les-librairies-python-pour-la-data-science/4740937-decouvrez-le-probleme-de-monty-hall#/id/r-4770995

(apologies for not providing an English version; I've been unable to find one)

I'm confused with lines 31-34, supposed to simulate the host opening another door after the first choice has been made:

```py
if first_choice == good_door:
    doors.remove(doors[randint(0,1)])
else:
    doors = [good_door]
```

Can someone explain how this piece of code consists in the host selecting a door other than the selected one?

Thanks!

Comment: You need the line(s) before this piece of code. The “good door” is removed from the list, so it will not be available.

Comment: It's not the good door which is removed before, but the door initially selected by the player (line 28). What I don't understand is why one of the two remaining doors is removed *if the good door was first selected*, else only the good door remains. My understanding of Monty Hall is that the host opens (remove) one of the remaining doors, regardless of which one the player selected.

Comment: You're right. You should still see the code in the context of the rest of the code. If the strategy is “change” then you either have the possibility to select the bad door (if you stand by the good) or select the good door (if you stand by a bad door)